# how do you adjust bootstrap form and button to be the same height inside a div?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the below HTML and CSS - how do I make the `search-bar` and `add-contacts` the same height? I currently have their height set to 100% in CSS to expand inside their container div but that doesn't work Is it possible to change their height even though they are bootstrap units?

[image]
**HTML**

```
  <div className="container">
    <form className="form-inline search-bar" role="form">
      <div className="form-group has-success has-feedback">
        <label className="control-label" htmlFor="inputSuccess4"></label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="inputSuccess4" type="text" placeholder="Search" onChange={handleChange}/>
        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-search flipped form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div className="add-contacts">
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        + Contacts Keeper
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table-container {
  margin: 20px;
}

.search-bar {
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.add-contacts {
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: get the height of .form-group class and assign it to the button's max-height using jquery

Answer (score 0):

Just change the height of the search bar.

Or you could put search bar in same div as add contacts bar.

Answer (score 0):

I find simpler is better with Bootstrap. I try to avoid adding custom CSS for most of the HTML elements already styled by Bootstrap:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="col-md-3 text-left">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Search</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Search">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">+ add stuff</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```